# ESP32 debugging with only six-pin PROG interface

Tags: eclipse, debugging, gdb, esp8266, esp32

I have a board with an esp32 on it. It only has the six-pin PROG interface on it and I can program it using an esp-prog board and the PROG interface. But because it does not have a JTAG interface, what is the best way to debug a program on this board. Is it possible to set breakpoints and step through the code using the PROG interface?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. This is just a glorified UART for talking to the bootloader. You need JTAG for debugging.

Comment: Thank you very much for this clarification. Do I understand it right that the PROG interface must be used for programming and the JTAG interface for debugging? So if you want to be able to debug, you need both interfaces?

Comment: You can use the JTAG interface and openocd for programming the Flash, see the [ESP IDF manual](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-guides/jtag-debugging/index.html#upload-application-for-debugging). But PROG is better supported by Espressif toolchain, it's a tad easier to use.